# PHP date_default_timezone_set() function on Localhost

Tags: php

I have a question regarding PHP `date_default_timezone_set()` function.

I'm trying to use this function to set my own time zone `(Africa/Cairo)` for my PHP code and it's not working at all.

I'm working on Localhost and I don't know if this note is important or not.

Anyways, This is my code to grab the UNIX timestamp:

```
$dateTime =  time();
```

And this is the code for the timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');
```

Also tried this one and the same not working:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Africa/Cairo');
```

And I'm using this code to show the date and time:

```
$date = new DateTime("@$dateTime");

echo "Date: " . $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br> Time: " . $date->format("h:i:s A");
```

This always giving me wrong time, The date is fine.

Kindly I need your advice if this code is the right way to do this or there are another advanced and accurate code for this operation.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Please define what is "wrong". What *should* it do, what exactly *does* it do? Show some concrete values.

Comment: What is wrong as I mentioned that the time comes with a very big difference .. It's not accurate .. This is the exact code that I'm using .. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but it's a lot more helpful if you also show what values you get. It's unclear whether something is actually wrong, or whether you may simply be expecting the wrong thing. Tell us what time it is right now and what UNIX timestamp and output date you get so we can diagnose the problem better.

Comment: Well .. For example (live example) the time was 2:48 PM and it show 09:48:57 PM

Comment: [Its working fine for me](https://eval.in/407500)

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime without any parameters...

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

If you pass a unix timestamp you will get the time in UTC as that is what a unix timestamp is relative to.

Comment: Thank for your reply .. But what if I need to use UNIX timestamp? As you mentioned it's automatically get it in UTC .. How can I customize it?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are many people suffering from timezone problems.

Finally I found these functions `date_add()` and `date_sub()` which add or subtract any value on your date or time.

Example:

```
date_add($date , date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 Hours"));
```

This will simply add 7 hours to your time. Check out full [date_add()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) and [date_sub()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sub.php) references on php.net.

> These functions is like a saver sometimes but sure it's better to find
>   your own timezone.

Comment: For the record, I'm pretty sure this is the wrong solution, because **offsets vary throughout the year!** But it's impossible to suggest the correct solution with the little information given.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,, But some countries have fixed time it's not changing .. And also I don't think PHP will add a useful function like this for no reason.

Comment: Yes, `DateInterval::createFromDateString` exists to create `DateInterval` objects from readable strings. `DateIntervals` are probably *not* primarily intended to be used for timezone offset fudging, that's what the entire `DateTimeZone` infrastructure is for.

Comment: Thanks for clarification .. I wasn't talking about date_interval_create_from_date_string() function .. I was talking about date_add() and date_sub() functions .. Thanks again for the information provided.